# cant find exe in reference project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Helle, I have two projects(Project1 & Project2) and i am trying to run Project1 within Project2.

I created a form (Form1) in a project(Project1) and compiled it. Then I add the .exe file from project1 to project2 by adding it as a reference in the References folder in Solution Explorer, i declared a namespace

```
using Project1;
```

and tried to call using the following code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process LoadProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
LoadProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "Project1.Form1";
LoadProcess.Start();
```

Then i get the error message cannot find file.

Comment: Well, do you have a file on disk named `Project1.Form1` that can be executed?

Comment: If you already have a reference to the executable containing that form, can't you simply do: `new Project1.Form1();`?

Comment: received with thanks.

Comment: when your `Form1` is compiled, you get an `.exe` format in your output directory. So, try using `LoadProcess.StartInfo.FileName =  @"foldername\Project1.exe"` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to start the `Project1` with a `Process` you don't really need the reference in the solution explorer.

All you need is to put your *.exe file of your compiled `Project1` which is probably called `Project1.exe` into the same folder where `Project2.exe` is.
After that change this line:

```
LoadProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "Project1.exe";
```

The process needs a real filename with extension. Or the entire path to this file if it is in some other folder.

But if you have already a reference I would follow Lasse V. Karlsen's lead. The solution from his comment is a much more elegant and simple solution. Just use the `Form1` in your code.